# ElasticSearch returns when querying new Index

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

We're getting the following error intermittently when creating and then querying a solitary index as part of an ElasticSearch test:

```
SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed]
```

We're using Elasticsearch 0.90.11, and the latest Ruby client. It seemed to happen less frequently when there was only one shard specified in `elasticsearch.yml`, but we still got the error intermittently.

Comment: What does the elasticsearch log say?

Answer (score 3):

After creating the index, do this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=yellow
```

That'll wait for the primary shards to be allocated before returning.